# Regex for allowing particular Special Characters

Tags: regex

I need a regex for allowing list of special characters((_-.$@?,:'/!) and letters supporting utf-8 languages.

I tried

```
/^[\_\-\.\$@\?\,\:\'\/\!]*$/
```

but typing letters in English and Tamil shows invalid.

Comment: From the FAQ: ***Please include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using, together with this tag (regex).***. The Unicode support is very different in the different regex engines, so the language is really needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the hyphen for it to be valid. You also don't need to escape most of the other characters - inside of brackets, almost everything is literal.

```
/[_\-.$@?,:'/!]*/
```

Comment: I misunderstood your question; you may want to use a blacklist instead of a whitelist. Are there specific special characters you want to disallow? In that case, use a negated character class of the form `[^...]` and specify the special characters you *don't* want to allow after the caret.

Comment: Its ok. But while using blacklist may miss some characters, so i want to tell only the valid characters.

Comment: I think you might find that it's harder to describe all "letters supporting UTF-8 languages" in a regular expression than it is to simply describe symbols that shouldn't be permitted. Where are you using this regex? What constraints does it need to satisfy?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if your regex engine supports `\p{L}`. You can try this:

```
^[_\-.\$@\?\,\:\'/!\p{L}]*$
```

or this one:

```
^[_\-.\$@\?\,\:\'/!\w]*$
```

The last one also matches digits.

Comment: Thanks. Its working for English and special characters, but not supporting other languages like tamil..

Comment: @vignesh, Hm... Both  these regexes should match Unicode letters.

Comment: @vignesh, For test purpose try this `\w` regex. Does it match tamil letters. It seems your regex engine has incorrect implementation.